# Jquery script not loading properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

Below is the simple code. When someone press button it will draw an image that can be re sized or re scaled and is movable
Below code works fine but if i move my java script above my canvas tag in my head tag
Below  script src = https://ajax.googleapis......
the code suddenly stops working
m curious as to what trigger this event and how to solve it

**CODE:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>fabric.js-simple text display</title>

    <!-- Get version 1.1.0 of Fabric.js from CDN -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.1.0/fabric.all.min.js" ></script>

    <!-- Get the highest 1.X version of jQuery from CDN. Required for ready() function. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

    <body>
        <!-- A canvas tag is required or 
             Fabric.js doesn't know where to draw. -->

        <canvas id="myCanvas" height=600 width=800></canvas>
        <input id="addStuff" type="button" value="Add!" />
    </body>

    <script>

        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        $(function(){
            $('#addStuff').on('click', function(e) {

                fabric.Image.fromURL('http://i.imgur.com/a47Yxsb.png', function(oImg) {
                    oImg.scaleToWidth(90);
                    oImg.left=50;
                    oImg.top = 50;
                    canvas.add(oImg);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>


</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem.

With the code as you show it, the following part is executed as the page loads :

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

While the jQuery code right under those 2 lines are executed when document is ready (your syntax is similar to `$( document ).ready( handler )`).

The problem is that the DOM is loaded from up to bottom , so if you place the 2 first lines on top of your document, by the time they are executed the HTML elements that are below don't exist yet, which causes a Javascript error as you refer to the `myCanvas` element, which doesn't exist at this time.

So you could for example move those 2 lines in the jQuery "ready" function below , and in that case you could put this function wherever you wish, even on top of your document, as they won't be executed before the whole DOM is loaded. The best place to put it would be in a separate javascript file though, and last time I checked the best place to include those .js files was at the very bottom of the body.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're doing stuff with the DOM. In the working case the JS is ran after everything in the body tag has loaded, including the element you want to add your handler to, so everything works fine. When you put it in the head tag the DOM hasn't loaded when the code is executed so it fails.

Been caught out by this one many times, you can also avoid this by adding all your js to $(document).ready() which waits for the document to be ready before running ie

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    $('#addStuff').on('click', function(e) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: This is partially false. The problem is in the 2 lines before the jQuery statement, which is similar to the one you propose as a solution (cfr [jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)), but indeed the problem is because of the reference to DOM elements that wouldn't be loaded yet if that code was put on top of the page.

Comment: m already using $(function() which is equlent to $(document).ready(function()
i guess bartdude has a point i will try that

Comment: ah yes you're quite right, that was more of a brain fart on the code example than anything else. Glad you got your answer, will edit for the sake of accuracy